# cannot import name 'CatBoostRegressor'

Tags: python, catboost, catboostregressor

I successfully installed catboost using pip install, but when i import the catboostregressor in my code it is throwing below error:

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor

ImportError: cannot import name 'CatBoostRegressor'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you probably have another module called catboost (maybe the one you're working in). Can you check if `import catboost` imports the correct catboost module?

Comment: if your environment is python3, try `pip3 install catboost`

Comment: also check any virtual environment is activated

Comment: pip3 install catboost also did not solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Issue is with the file name catboost.py

After renaming the file name. Issue is solved.